# Move android widget to tray

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, tray

Some default widgets like "direct contact dial" are moveable to the favorites tray [1].
How can I create such a widget that is moveable to the favorites tray?

[1] http://developer.android.com/design/get-started/ui-overview.html

Best regards.

Comment: What is "the system (ics) dock"? Please consider posting an annotated screenshot indicating what you are referring to.

Comment: Sorry, the "dock" is called "favorites tray". I edited my question and added a link.

Comment: Those aren't widgets. They are application icons. Any application icon can be dragged there.

Comment: I know that it's possible to move application icons to the tray but it's also possible for widgets. Try it with any ics device and the "direct dial a contact"-widget.

Comment: How interesting. It's not merely a 1x1 app widget, as some of mine don't work. ConnectBot's app widget works, but their source repository is apparently out of date, as their manifest does not show any app widget in it... :-(

Comment: They are not widgets. They are shortcuts. I know because I wrote ConnectBot. See my answer below for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are shortcuts. You can have the ability to add shortcuts by handling the [`ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT) intent in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.  The Activity that handles this action should present something to allow the user to select which item in your application to create a shortcut to.